# Using the same server SSL certificate for multiple purposes

Tags: security, windows-phone-8, push-notification, ssl-certificate, apple-push-notifications

We have a backend server that services a multi-platform app that will be launched on iOS, Windows 8, Windows Phone 8 and Android. We'd like to use in production as few certificates as possible (preferably just one) to attain the following purposes:

- secure communication (HTTPS) with the client application
- authentication to the Windows Phone Push Notifications Service
- authentication to the Apple Push Notifications Service

Besides taking care that the certificate is issued by a common trusted root authority, are there any other impediments that could prevent a single certificate from being used simultaneously for all these? Is it a viable possibility or is it instead necessary to resort to one certificate for each of the above purposes?

Answer (score 1):

Gabriel I guess there is a problem. Main one is that `HTTPS` certificate private key cannot be coded by a secret this kind of certificate contain `*.crt` and `*.key` file which are not secured. When You want authenticate yourself or server in some Service for example Windows phone push like you have listed there is need to create hash for your private key with secret aka pin or password. What make You use at least two different certificates.

Second thing is that purpose of using certificates is to validate the issuer and to authenticate user/service provider. `HTTPS` ssl certificate issued by a trusted `CA` show to the user `Hey this is trusted website You should not be afraid passing sensitive data through the service`, and the certificates which are used to authenticate are just saying `Hey its me I am authorized to use this application`
 Purpose of those certificates and different so certificates them self should be different. Using the same `cert` for actions like You have listed cause necessaries vulnerabilities  and is highly NOT RECOMMENDED

Comment: I'm not sure I understand yet the first point: depending on what you state that you want to use the certificate for in the signing request, you get from root authorities different certificate formats? As for the 2nd point, it would be an acceptable compromise for us, a single "superset" certificate that encapsulates both traffic encryption and authentication, I'm not sure it really is such a groundbreaking security hole.

Comment: You are right it is possible to use the same `cert` for both encryption and authentication. I say that there is possibility to create a password that decrypt your private key which is used to validate the certificate. To authenticate HTTPS traffic such operation does not make sense but in situation to sign requests its highly recommended as I have posted

Comment: I realized I still don't understand very well if the same certificate can be used both in IIS (for HTTPS) and in application code for authorization to other (Push) services. Can't I just export it from IIS and embed it with a password in a .pfx file? I guess I have to read some more and get back...

Comment: Theoretically it is possible, but once more, its not recommended.